# How do i find and get the <style> code part of the javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At this site:

[Examples](http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/)

There is the example called MULTILINES SIMPLE EXAMPLE.
I can get it to work but without the style the visual like in the website of the demo.
This is my working code so far:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
<ul id="nt-example1">
                            <li>Etiam imperdiet volutpat libero eu tristique. Aenean, rutrum felis in. <a href="#">Read more...</a></li>
                            <li>Curabitur porttitor ante eget hendrerit adipiscing. Maecenas at magna. <a href="#">Read more...</a></li>
                            <li>Praesent ornare nisl lorem, ut condimentum lectus gravida ut. <a href="#">Read more...</a></li>
                            <li>Nunc ultrices tortor eu massa placerat posuere. Vivamus viverra sagittis. <a href="#">Read more...</a></li>
                            <li>Morbi sodales tellus sit amet leo congue bibendum. Ut non mauris eu neque. <a href="#">Read more...</a></li>
                            <li>In pharetra suscipit orci sed viverra. Praesent at sollicitudin tortor, id. <a href="#">Read more...</a> </li>
                            <li>Maecenas nec ligula sed est suscipit aliquet sed eget ipsum, suspendisse. <a href="#">Read more...</a></li>
                            <li>Onec bibendum consectetur diam, nec euismod urna venenatis eget.. <a href="#">Read more...</a> </li>
                        </ul>
<script>
var nt_example1 = $('#nt-example1').newsTicker({
    row_height: 80,
    max_rows: 3,
    duration: 400,
    prevButton: $('#nt-example1-prev'),
    nextButton: $('#nt-example1-next')
});
</script>
```

So the text in the lines is scrolling but i don't have the arrows and the lines and the colors like in the website of the example.
I see just simple text scrolling up.

I tried to go to the demo page source view :

```
view-source:http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/
```

But i didn't see there the part of the  
In the website of the demo of the exmaples near each example there is the  simple code but not the visuals the style.

Comment: in the css loaded along with the page?

Comment: https://github.com/risq/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/tree/master/assets/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They style their examples in main.css which is called in the header of the page.

`http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/css/main.css`

The relevant styles start at line 490:

```
/* nt-example1 */

#nt-example1 {
max-width: 620px;
margin: auto;
}

#nt-example1-container {
text-align: center;
}

#nt-example1-container i {
font-size: 36px;
margin: 8px;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

#nt-example1-container i:hover {
color: #333;
}

#nt-example1 li {
color: #4e4e4e;
background: #F2F2F2;
overflow: hidden;
height: 80px;
padding: 10px;
line-height: 30px;
list-style: none;
font-size: 24px;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #2c8162;
}

#nt-example1 li:hover {
background: #FFF;
}
```